# Count Objects before OutOfMemoryError (Java)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to compare different types of GC by running code below with 4 types of keys.

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        System.out.println("Finalized.");
    }

    public static void showInfo() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("##### Heap utilization statistics [bytes] #####");
        System.out.println("Used memory: " + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) + " bytes");
        System.out.println("Free memory: " + runtime.freeMemory() + " bytes");
        System.out.println("Total memory: " + (runtime.totalMemory()) + " bytes");
        System.out.println("Max memory: " + (runtime.maxMemory()) + " bytes");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("Start...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 54000; i++) {
            num++;
            new User("Bob", 25);
        }
        System.out.println("Objects created before error: " + num);
        showInfo();
        System.out.println("Finish.");
    }
}
```

The keys are (each represents one of the GC type):

```
-XX:+UseSerialGC
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

And I'm using a small 3mb heap (`-Xmx3mb`).

So, the question is how to count number of created objects before OutOfMemoryError (before Java Heap Space error) ? I mean in that code the number of created objects is 54000, but if I'm trying to create more (70000, 80000, etc), I have an error and don't know after what number of object the exception is thrown. Is there a good way to count, how many objects we can create before OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: You can force a heap dump, then examine that with eclipse MAT.

Comment: Can you catch the error and then output `num`?

Comment: @SteveSmith If you get an out of memory error, you may not have additional memory to required to perform further actions

Comment: @SteveSmith, I tried to do that, using try/catch block, but nothing happened, just a short message "Java heap space error"

Comment: Keep in mind that `finalize` overrides significantly alter how object memory is managed, and might not even run. They tend to prevent collection of an instance, at least for a while. Your `finalize` method serves little purpose and will likely corrupt your evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("Start...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 54000; i++) {
            try {
                new User("Bob", 25);
                num++;
            } catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Objects created before error: " + num);
        showInfo();
        System.out.println("Finish.");
    }
```

You have to catch the exception and only increment the counter if the object is succefully created.

Comment: that shouldn't create an OOME

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @njzk2: in this specific case, the fact that `User` has a custom `finalize()` method is the actual cause of `OutOfMemoryError`s that might be thrown, as there is no guaranty that the finalizer thread catches up with the allocation rate, so there will be tons of objects hanging in the finalization queue. Of course, such a test doesn’t say anything about the chosen garbage collection algorithm.